# difference between deployment task and deployment project in bamboo

Tags: deployment, bamboo

Difference between deployment task and deployment project in bamboo. Both is used to deploy binaries in relative place how can I sure which one is used in which time / scenario

Answer (score 2):

Deployment projects encompass the releases, deployment environments, and tasks for deployment environments. You can often use the same tasks (e.g., SSH task) in a Bamboo build plan that you can in a deployment project. Technically, you can use build plans to deploy your artifacts to different environments if you choose - however the deployment projects give you several advantages:

1. Better notifications
2. Better automation (once you set up
   environments, it's a 0 or 1-click deployment)
3. Separate environment profiles and visibility as to which releases are
   deployed and where
4. Releases

... and more

Answer (score 0):

I have made a bamboo plan and for which I made a deployment project which run when the plan complete build successfully. I just want to know that there is task type in bamboo plan 'Deployment Task' which also used to deploy files like my deployment project.